# Pentaho dashboard doesn't display graphics

Tags: tomcat, pentaho, dashboard, base-url

When trying to view dashboards, these are only displayed, when locally connected via RDP to the server.

When trying to view them from remote (not connected via rdp to the server) by hostname, the images won't be shown.

**Cause:** Images are redirected to http://localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file:

- biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\web.xml

and change the part of the base-url:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>base-url</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:8081/pentaho/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

change localhost to the fqdn. i.e. https://mybi.mycompany.com/pentaho/

Restart BI Server and you're done.
Now the images will be shown.